# How to prove that $\sum^{n}_{k=0}\begin{pmatrix} n \\ k \end{pmatrix}\frac{(-1)^{k}(2k)!!}{k!}=(-1)^{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, factorial

I'm trying to normalise a function and the normalisation is complete if I can prove that $$\sum^{n}_{k=0}\begin{pmatrix}
n \\ 
k 
\end{pmatrix}\frac{(-1)^{k}(2k)!!}{k!}=(-1)^{n}$$
where $i!!$ is the double factorial, e.g if $k=3$, $(2k)!!=6!!=6\times 4\times 2$. Evaluating for the first few values of $n$ it is clear that this is true, however I haven't encountered a series like this before and therefore don't know where to start. Any ideas?

Comment: You have $(-1)^k$ twice. Is that a typo? If not, then the summand is positive and the series couldn’t equal a negative number.

Comment: Yes, for (2k)!! gets cancelled with k! and you will have just $2^k$ left but that $(-1)^k$ twice is a problem.

Comment: Because i think then the answer will be just $3^n$

Comment: sorry the $(-1)^{k}$ was a typo

Comment: How do they cancel??

Comment: @AdrienAmour $(2k)!! = 2^k k!$. Because e.g. $6\cdot4\cdot2 =  (2\cdot3)\cdot(2\cdot2)\cdot(2\cdot1) = 2^33!$.

Comment: And after that you're left with $(1-2)^n$ expanded.

Comment: See (2k)!!=(2k)(2k-2)....(2k-(2k-2)) or (2k)!!=(2.k)(2.(k-1))(2.(k-2))....(2.1) so there are k terms taking 2 common we will have $2^k.{k.(k-1)...1}$ which will be k!.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, being from a physics student it really helps to see a different perspective!